# How to get the json result from struts2 action methode thru ajax(Using jquery)

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, struts2

I have used below code to display countryCode in front end  onchange of country from the dropdown thru ajax.But I am not able to get the json result from the action class to the front end. Can any one help me out to resolve this problem ?.

**Struts.xml file:**

```
<result-types>
  <result-type name="json" class="com.googlecode.jsonplugin.JSONResult"/>
</result-types>
<action name="populateCountryCode"
class="com.CustRegnManagerAction "method="populateCountryCode">
  <result name="success" type="json">
    <param name="root">jsonData</param>
  </result>
</action>
```

**Action class method:**

```
public String populateCountryCode() throws Exception
   {
     jsonData = new HashMap<String, String>();

    try{
         if(!getCountry().equals("") && getCountry()!=null){

             List<Country> countryCodeNew =(List<Country>) custRegnManagerService.getCountryCode(getCountry());
             for(Country country: countryCodeNew){

                 countryCode=country.getCountryCode();

                  jsonData.put("countryCode", countryCode);
                 // setJsonData(jsonData);
             }
        System.out.println(jsonData);
        }
     }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
         e.printStackTrace();
    }

     return SUCCESS;
}
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
//checks for the button click event
$("#country").change(function(e){


var countryCode=$('#countryCode').val();
var country=$('#country').val();

 $.getJSON(      
  'populateCountryCode.action' ,
  {
      country: country
  },
  function(json) {
       alert("hi")  ****//not displaying
   $('#countryCode').html(json.countryCode);

   countryCode=json.countryCode; 
  }
 );
 return false;
});  
});
```

**jsp code:**

```
<s:form action="addRegistFeedback" method="post" id="theform" >

<s:select  headerKey="-1" headerValue="--- Select ---"

 label="Country"   id="country"     cssStyle="width:100%" list="countries" 

required="true" name="country">  </s:select><br>

<table style="width: 25%">
<tr style="width: 100%">
<td ><s:label theme="simple">Phone :</s:label>
</td>
<td style="width: 70%">

<s:textfield   name="customer.countryCode"id="countryCode" cssStyle="width:20%" 
theme="simple" required="true" />

<s:textfield name="stateCode"  cssStyle="width:20%" id="stateCode"
theme="simple"   required="true"  />

<s:textfield name="cityCode"  cssStyle="width:45%" id="phone"
theme="simple"   required="true" />
</td>
</tr>
</table><br>
<s:token name="token"></s:token>

<s:submit value="Save" id="button" theme="simple" cssStyle="width:50px;"></s:submit>
</s:form>
```

Comment: Can you post the error or nondesired output you are getting? This will help us understand your problem better and allow us to help you.

Comment: The  function(function(json) {$('#countryCode').html(json.countryCode);}) shows nothing..that means its not returning any value inside the jsp page...

Comment: I can able to display the countryCode for the corresponding country  in console...is dat any configuration problem or wt?...I tried to display alert msg inside the jquery function(mentioned in the prev comment) bt its not displaying.. why? that function itself not working..

Answer (score 0):

Please create a getter setter method of the map jsonData in your action class.This might help you in resolving your issue.